# REST API calls using async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

Here's my code snippet

```
var clients = require('restify-clients');

async function callApi(val){
        const client = clients.createJsonClient({ url: apiUrl });
        await client.get('/my/url', (err, req, res, obj) => {
            if (err) {
                return err;
            } else {
                return obj;
            }
        });
}
```

I've tried a few ways of calling it, but they all aren't working

First way:

```
var results = await callApi(val);
```

Second way:

```
var results = callApi(val).then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`client.get` doesn't return a promise, you can't use `await` on a function which doesn't return a promise (honestly you can, but it doesn't make sense). The correct solution here is to *promisify* `client.get` and return a promise:

```
function callApi(val) {
  const client = clients.createJsonClient({ url: apiUrl });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.get('/my/url', (err, req, res, obj) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(obj);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Usage
let results = await callApi(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove await from results

```
var results = callApi(val);
```

Comment: Can't. `callApi` is `async`